mathematical notation related to function sets
Let $n$ function sets: $A_1=\{A_1^1,A_1^2,\cdots, A_1^{j_1}\}$; $A_2=\{A_2^1,A_2^2,\cdots, A_2^{j_2}\}; $... $A_n=\{A_n^1,A_n^2,\cdots, A_n^{j_n}\}$;
Let's define $m=\prod_{k=1}^n j_k$ and let $C=\{c^1,c^2,\cdots, c^m\}$.
I like to do the cartesian product of the sets $A_k, k=1,..., n$ and then multiply in a lexicographical order/rank the $c$'s and then sum them. How do I write this in a math notation? 
Example, $n=3$, $j_1=2$, $j_2=3$, $j_3=1$, so $m=6$. So I have:$A_1^1A_2^1A_3^1c^1+A_1^1A_2^2A_3^1c^2+A_1^1A_2^3A_3^1c^3+A_1^2A_2^1A_3^1c^4+A_1^2A_2^2A_3^1c^5+A_1^2A_2^3A_3^1c^6$

If I understand you correctly, the set of all such formal expressions is $C \to \prod_{k=1}^n A_k$.

@NaïmFavier The cartesian product for $n=3$ in the example above is an orderly triplet  set $${A_1^1A_2^1A_3^1, A_1^1A_2^2A_3^1, A_1^1A_2^3A_3^1, A_1^2A_2^1A_3^1, A_2^1A_2^2A_3^1,A_1^2A_2^3A_3^1}$$  Multiply each element of the set by the corresponding $c$, so the first element by $c^1$, the second element by $c^2$ and so on, and then add them up to obtain $$A_1^1A_2^1A_3^1c^1+A_1^1A_2^2A_3^1c^2+A_1^1A_2^3A_3^1c^3+A_1^2A_2^1A_3^1c^4+A_2^1A_2^2A_3^1c^5+A_1^2A_2^3A_3^1c^6$$ is that clear? thanks
